# How to send data frame from r to SQL?

Tags: sql, r

```
#setwd('Desktop/IE332')
install.packages("wakefield")
install.packages("RMySQL")
install.packages("randomNames")
install.packages('password')
install.packages('OpenRepGrid')
library(RMySQL)
library(password)
library(wakefield)
library(randomNames)

industriesData <- read.csv('Industries.csv')
skills <- read.csv('Skills.csv')
sp500 <- read.csv("http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/sandp500.csv")
companies <- sample(sp500$Name, 100)

locations <- c('Northwest', 'Midwest', 'Northeast', 'South', 'Southwest', 'Southeast', 
'International') # Locations
gpas <- c(4,3.5,3,2.5,2)
n <- 100
locPrefs <- numeric(n)

studentSkills <- matrix(nrow=100,ncol=10) 
studentInd <- matrix(nrow=100,ncol=5)
jobSkills <- matrix(nrow=100,ncol=5)
for(j in 1:n){ # Samples random skills assigned to students
  studentSkills[j,] <- sample(skills[,1],10,replace=FALSE)
  studentInd[j,] <- sample(industriesData[,1],5,replace=FALSE)
  jobSkills[j,] <- sample(skills[,1],5,replace=FALSE)
}

studentData <- data.frame('first names'=randomNames(n, which.names = 'first'),'last 
names'=randomNames(n, which.names = 'last'),'username'=seq(1, 
n),'password'=password(8,numbers=TRUE),'gpa'=gpa(n, mean = 85.356, sd = 3.2, name = 
"GPA"),'visa'=sample(c("N","Y"), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.78, .22)), 'loc 
pref'=sample(locations,n,replace = TRUE), 'skill'=studentSkills, 'Industry'=studentInd) # Student data
employerData <- data.frame('company names'=companies, 'pref 
gpa'=sample(gpas,n,replace=TRUE), 'sponser?'=sample(c('N','Y'), size=n, replace = TRUE, prob 
= c(.78, .22)), 'job id'=sample(seq(100,999),n,replace=FALSE),'pref skill'=jobSkills, 
'industry'=sample(industriesData[,1],n,replace=TRUE),'location'=sample(locations,n,replace = 
TRUE)) # Employer data
```

I am trying to send certain columns of the studentData and employerData to tables in SQL, how would i go about doing that? I have a table named students where I would like to upload the first and last names of the studentsData data frame into this SQL table.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are many tutorials and examples on the web. Try for example https://db.rstudio.com/

Comment: *"send certain columns"*: `studentData[,c(1,2,5)]` or `studentData[,c("col1","col3","col99")]`. *"send ... to tables in SQL"* ... `dbWriteTable` is well documented.